# In Flow, can I declare a function signature so I can reuse it wherever I want?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

In JavaScript it is quite common for callbacks to have pretty common signatures, like this:

```
function(error, result) { }
```

However, in Flow, I have to declare this function signature everywhere.

What I'm looking for is the possibility to give a function signature a name, so I could use it like this:

```
function(callback: callbackFunction) {
    // callbackFunction here is the function signature (error:string, result: any): void;
}
```

Does Flow support something like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you are looking for [**type aliases**](http://flowtype.org/docs/type-aliases.html#_):

```
type callbackFunction = (string, any) => void;
```